# Gradle - Get the default value (convention) of a Property

Tags: gradle, groovy, default-value, gradle-properties

I want to achieve a very basic thing (in any normal language): I would like to get the default value (convention) of a Property. Gradle docs in chapter [Lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#applying_conventions), describes how to apply the convention to a Property:

```
def property = objects.property(String)

// Set a convention
property.convention("convention 1")
println("value = " + property.get())

// Can replace the convention
property.convention("convention 2")
println("value = " + property.get())

property.set("value")

// Once a value is set, the convention is ignored
property.convention("ignored convention")
println("value = " + property.get())
```

The problem is, that you cannot query the `property` to get information what is the convention (the default value) when you set a value. It seems that the only way it's to clear (nullify) the value:

```
property.value(null).get()
```

But this is just stupid because you are doing unnecessary actions, while the convention is somewhere there?

Does anyone know how to get it without clearing the value?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to get the original default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (for 2022) is: No, you can't get the default value (convention) of a Property.

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to answer why `set` overrides the `convention` once it's called.  The `convention` is the default value, once the property has a value by calling `set` the `convention` is ignored because the property has a value.  That makes sense because that's what a default value should mean.  If I have a value use that otherwise use this default value.  `Convention` and `set` seem to follow that pattern.  I don't quite follow why this is surprising to how you want to use gradle, but just as an outside observer I think gradle is doing what is expected.

You can test if a property exists using

```
if( property.isPresent() ) {
    // do whatever
}
```

I bet that `isPresent()` is going to say false when the convention would be returned by `get()`, but if you call `set` then `isPresent()` is going to return `true`.

Then there are other methods to help like:

```
def val = property.getOrElse( "SomeDefault" )
def maybe = property.getOrNull()
```

I do think Gradle doesn't always do a good job of making the API very accessible from their home page and docs (ie groovydoc) for answering more complex questions:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html

These methods are the super interface Provider and hence why it may not be obvious they are available if you don't look up the chain:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html

Comment: Thank you, but this is totally not what I was asking about. I read the documentation, and I know how it works :) My question was, how to get the default value, after the value is set. It is somewhere there, as I wrote in the question, because when you nullify the value, it will return convention (the default value)

Comment: Other than rooting around using reflection you can't using the Property interface.  There are no methods to read the convention back (ie getConvention()).  You could use reflection or some assumptions about the implementation of that interface and possibly figure it out, but these aren't going to be portable and could easily break.